# Converting Array of Strings in Spark to byte array and retrieving it back using UDFs

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark

I am trying to convert Array of Strings to byte-array in Spark and re-converting the byte-array to Array of Strings.

However, I am not getting the String array back as I intend. Here is the code -

```
// UDFs for converting Array[String] to byte array and get back Array[String] from byte array
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper 

val mapper: ObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper
mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)

val convertToByteArray = udf((map: Seq[String]) => mapper.writeValueAsBytes(map))
val convertToString = udf((a: Array[Byte])=> new String(a))

val arrayDF = Seq(
  ("x100", Array("p1","p2","p3","p4"))
).toDF("id", "myarray")
arrayDF.printSchema()
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- myarray: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
arrayDF.show(false)
+----+----------------+
|id  |myarray         |
+----+----------------+
|x100|[p1, p2, p3, p4]|
+----+----------------+

val converted = arrayDF.withColumn("bytearray", convertToByteArray($"myarray")).select($"id",$"bytearray")
converted.printSchema()
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- bytearray: binary (nullable = true)
converted.show(false)
+----+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|id  |bytearray                                                       |
+----+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|x100|[5B 22 70 31 22 2C 22 70 32 22 2C 22 70 33 22 2C 22 70 34 22 5D]|
+----+----------------------------------------------------------------+

val getBack = converted.withColumn("getstring", convertToString($"bytearray")) 
getBack.printSchema()
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- bytearray: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- getstring: string (nullable = true)
getBack.show(false)
+----+----------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
|id  |bytearray                                                       |getstring            |
+----+----------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
|x100|[5B 22 70 31 22 2C 22 70 32 22 2C 22 70 33 22 2C 22 70 34 22 5D]|["p1","p2","p3","p4"]|
+----+----------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
```

However, I want my final results as -

```
+----+----------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
|id  |bytearray                                                       |getstring            |
+----+----------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
|x100|[5B 22 70 31 22 2C 22 70 32 22 2C 22 70 33 22 2C 22 70 34 22 5D]|[p1,p2,p3,p4]|
+----+----------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
```

Here is the `pom.xml` that I use for creating byte-array

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

you take a list of strings and and treat it as a single object and at the conversion back you treat it as if was just a string- if you want a single string back you also need to convert the list to a string:

```
val convertToByteArray = udf((map: Seq[String]) => mapper.writeValueAsBytes(map.mkString("[",",","]")))
```

Comment: It still returns me as string, not an array of string. From your code, if I re-convert the byte array to string, I get `"[p1,p2,p3,p4]"`

Comment: because that's what you're doing you are getting a bytearray and converting to a string and in the initial conversion you're doing a  poor man's serialization of a string to a bytearray it wouldn't automagically serialize your Seq[String]

Comment: thank u for the explanation. So what is the correct way to serialize the `Seq[String]` such that I can get it back from the byte array?

Comment: you need a serializer e.g. Kyro (https://github.com/twitter/chill) or ProtoBuff etc.

Comment: alternatively you can use the conversion to string and later split the string and convert back to a sequence

Comment: for which option?